# how to add highlighted keywords in msvc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010-express

I have no intention of changing the syntax of anything or making the keyword be treated any differently during compilation. All I want is to have the token of my choice turn blue when i type it in msvc for my own visual purposes. Most IDE's allow for this kind of functionality, and i don't see why msvc, with all it's various bell's and whistles, does not. I would go and use another IDE, if intellisense wasn't so darn helpful -_-. Any help here gents?

btw, already found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy61y8b8%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). devenv.exe doesn't exist -_- .

edit: should also mention that i'm using msvc++ express. Think this is only available if i pay?

Comment: It does work. The only difference is that devenv.exe is called VCExpress.exe :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it does work, look in this tutorial:

http://arthy303.wordpress.com/2010/10/09/defining-keywords-in-visual-c/

I changed my_var to be always in red (using VS C++ 2010 Express):

[image]